# LINQ Order by column x and if empty take column y

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm building a simple messaging system with the following data model:

```
public partial class Conversation
{
    public Conversation()
    {
        this.Messages = new HashSet<Message>();
        this.Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
        this.MessagingHubConnections = new HashSet<MessagingHubConnection>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BoatId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public virtual Boat Boat { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MessagingHubConnection> MessagingHubConnections { get; set; }
}

public partial class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ConversationId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TimeSend { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

When a customer opens his account dashboard, I want to display a list of all the conversations. This should be ordered according to the following rule: The first conversation in the list is the one with a message with the latest `Message.TimeSent`. If the conversation has no messages, it has to pick the `Conversation.TimeCreated`.
The code below is what I have right now but this is obviously not working when a Conversation has no messages. The variable `conversations` in the code below is an `IQueryable<Conversation>`.

```
var orderedConversations = conversations.OrderByDescending(c => c.Messages.Max(m => m.TimeSend));
```

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: You mean `conversations` (with a `s`) is an `IQueryable` of `Conversation` instead of `Customer`?

Comment: My bad. I'll fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By projecting the `TimeSend` into `DateTime?` before `Max()`*-ing* it, you can obtain a `(DateTime?)null` when the collection is empty instead of getting an `InvalidOperationException`. And then, you can null-coalesce this result with `TimeCreated`:

```
var orderedConversations = conversations
    .OrderByDescending(c => 
        c.Messages
            .Select<Message, DateTime?>(x => x.TimeSend)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x)
            .FirstOrDefault() ??
        c.TimeCreated);
```

Comment: This is what I get: `'ICollection<Message>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<Message>' could be found (are you missing [..] reference?)`

Comment: I did a copy paste from your answer right away. variables `x` and `c` aren't used anywhere else in my code.

Comment: @JelleKerkstra My bad, forgot `Select` takes 2 generic types. See the updated answer.